# phpmyadmin not allowing MySQL functions in INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

I have this mysql database table called `relationships`. Here is the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `relationships` (
   `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL,
   `restaurant_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL,
   `company_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
   `role_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL,
   `created` DATETIME NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I tried using phpmyadmin to insert a new record but, for the life of me, it would not allow me to use the `NOW()` function to set the `created` field.

[image]

However, I succeeded when using the command line:

[image]

My question is, how to make mysql function work in an insert statement when using phpmyadmin?
Or, is it some kind of development environment configuration issue?
I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Have you tried `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` also for `DATETIME` field?

Comment: @JunM Thank you for the suggestion. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` works like a charm. It's rather strange. Why would `NOW()` not work? I believe it's a parsing bug.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch version 4.5.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with the linter (syntax checker) used by phpMyAdmin, but was fixed some time ago. Since 4.5.4 is about a year old and not supported anymore, I suggest you upgrade your phpMyAdmin installation. You can still press "Go" and the query will execute, the red 'x' is just a warning and doesn't prevent you from submitting your query (indeed, I just ran a similar query with that same version and it executed correctly despite the warning).

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, some times phpmyadmin query editor shows this error (cross) sign, Please try to refresh the page and run this query again.

I have recently run this code in phpmyadmin.